# Street starting and ending point - lan/lat

Tags: android, android-maps, android-location

I searched for this one for quite some time:
I want to when having a lan/lat of the "start" of the street, get the lan/lat of the "end" of the street, is that possible using the Android location API?  or even using the Google Maps API?

And another connected question is:
Can i get the above info when having a lan/lat of a point on the street(not the "start/end" of the street)?

Comment: You want to get the lat/lon when your are start/end of a street?